# Intermittent Swift Framework Compiler Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am trying out Swift in the XCode beta.  In particular using an @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable.  I am building a framework containing an (@IBDesignable) UIView subclass and a Simple iOS App in order to test it out (Both contained in and linked via a workspace).  After a few successful builds I get the following error in the framework build output:

:0: error: /Users/richardpj/Projects/Swift2/Swift2FW/build/Swift2FW.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Swift2FW.build/unextended-module.modulemap:2: umbrella header 'Swift2FW.h' not found
:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Swift2FW'

Before you ask I've done a clean and deleted my derived data but nothing seems to resolve it except deleting and recreating the workspace and project files.

Any ideas on the source of the error, how to replicate (for a bug report) OR am I being dumb.

**EDIT:** I've gotten 50 views since this was posted.  Sounds like it's a bug I should report.  Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: did you try to clean project, reset simulator then close / open Xcode? sometimes it could help.

Comment: Yes I've tried all that stuff and more.  Seems like the project file somehow gets corrupted.  Recreating it identically is the only fix that works for me so far.

Comment: You can report bugs [here](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Answer (score 8):

When making my own swift framework I got the error "could not build Objective-C module".

I fixed it by going to "Link Binary With Libraries" and adding "UIKit".

Answer (score 8):

In case if you are writing embedded framework in Swift check your Project Settings -> Framework Target Name -> Build Phases -> Headers. Currently (Xcode 6.2) any header file listed in Public section here can cause this error:

*`<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'YourFrameworkName'`*

Answer (score 5):

I was seeing this error when the .h umbrella file had the same name as one of my swift files. Once I changed the name of the swift file the framework built.

```
Ex. Project Name: TestProject
|_
  TestProject.h <=
  |_
    Models
    |_
      TestProject.swift <=
```

Having the two files with the arrows ( <= ) named the same caused the "could not build Objective-C module" error for me.

Comment: My files were not named that way.  The auto-generated test targets were however.  I'll give it a look and let you know.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Created a new Solution containing files named differently from the umbrella header.  Deleted the test targets and their files to be sure.  Still having the same issue.  After a few builds it gave the same error. :(

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a previous build setting that overrode Public Headers Folder Path `(PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH)` .  Clearing that to the (new?) default value of `$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/Headers` fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, all I had to do was open the "Edit Scheme" window (Product > Schemes > Edit Scheme) for the embedded Swift Framework target and uncheck "Shared".  I guess because non-embedded Swift frameworks aren't yet supported, sharing a framework scheme implies there must be an Objective-C component of the module.

You can also uncheck this in the "Manage Schemes" window (Product > Schemes > Manage Schemes...).

Answer (score 1):

After coming across this problem many times and sometime resorting to recreating the whole project I have found that this very strange build problem is normally caused by you having Breakpoints set.

Open the Breakpoint Navigator Window (CMD-7) and delete all the breakpoints.

This normally fixes this problem for me however bizarre it may sound.

It's very easy to accidentally add a breakpoint when you're clicking in the margin to investigate compilation errors.

Comment: My rationale mind says this is probably coincidence, but after I did remove the one Exception Breakpoint in the framework project I could also build the project that uses the framework. However it's been going away after some time (?) anyway so it could have been coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help anybody else but I had imported the ProjectName-Swift.h file into the ProjectName.h (umbrella header) file during some testing, and when I removed that import the error went away and I was able to build again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this turned out to be because I had failed to list the framework as a dependency in the build phases of my other target(s). As soon as I did that, all was well.

I presume that it is because this ensures that the framework is build before the target(s) that use it.

The reason this issue is intermittent is evidently that, without the dependency, the order of building is indeterminate — so sometimes it happens to be the right order and the build works, and other times it happens to be the wrong order and the build fails.